# Transit web app development (journey planner)

Tags: software-recommendations, navigation, transit

I am going to develop a journey planner (like Google transit).

Is there there any open source API available that can help me, or do I have to do everything on my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Open Trip Planner (Developer Section)**

> OTP Deployer  — The easiest way to get started with OTP is by using
>   OTP Deployer, an web-based utility provided by OpenPlans
>   Transportation. Deployer allows users to simply provide their transit
>   data in the standard GTFS formay, and the rest of the process — from
>   gathering street network data to building the graph object to
>   launching a live OTP web applcation — will be automated om Amazon’s
>   Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) platform. OTP Deployer can be used to
>   simply build graphs remotely (free of charge) or launch and host a
>   full OTP deployment (one-week “preview” hosting is free; long-term
>   paid hosting can also be arranged)

http://opentripplanner.com/users-developers/

**Rest API**

http://www.opentripplanner.org/apidoc/