# Error while starting OpenTripPlanner server

Tags: java, routing, tomcat, opentripplanner

I have started working with OpenTripPlanner (I am developing a journey planner app). I am following the two & five minute tutorial given on OpenTripPlanner website.
But while starting the server using "`bin\start-server.bat`" it's giving me errors which are shown in picture. I also tried to google for error messages but didn't find any fair solution.
[image: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\otp\bin>start-server]

Comment: lib folder exists in otp directory as bin

Comment: Background Information from Original Question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43163/transit-webapp-development-journey-planner/43166#comment56713_43166

Comment: Does it work if you run the java -jar lib\winstone from the otp directory, instead of the otp\bin directory?

Comment: Those two lines that start with # are comment lines in the script you copied this from. You aren't meant to run those.

Comment: thanks, bin\start-server.bat solve the problem i was starting  it by start-server.bat :)

Comment: now i have successfully run all the steps in 2 minutes and 5 minutes tutorial. but now i ran into another problem which is when i try to plan my route in webapp, an error pops out saying "we are sorry trip planner is temporarily unavailable please try again later". i think i am confused with this point *NOTE: it's very important to have the pre-built web app run from /otp (or C:\otp) directory. If you want to run from another location, you'll need to edit the file WEB-INF/classes/data-sources.xml within /otp/webapps/opentripplanner-api-webapp.war.

* in 2minutes tutorial

Comment: possible duplicate of [help with setting up opentripplanner](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43532/help-with-setting-up-opentripplanner)

Comment: @Khayam: please convert your followup (i.e. that you should run bin\start-server.bat) and post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

as shown in the comments

instead of

```
start-server.bat
```

you need to use:

```
bin\start-server.bat
```